# JS сохранить GET запрос после замены истории, при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли сохранить GET при перезагрузке страницы после изменения истории:

```
history.replaceState(null, '', location.pathname);
```

`dp/aaa/bbb?A=1` 
адрес без get выглядит лаконичней `dp/aaa/bbb`, но после перезагрузки как и должно быть get запроса нет. Возможно ли эти параметры сохранить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу так:

```
/**
* GETRequest - сохраненный get запрос
* GETPath - страница которой принадлежит сохраненный get
*/
(function () {
  // если нет get запроса и какой-то запрос сохранен
  if(window.sessionStorage.GETRequest && window.location.search==""){
      // если юзер обновил страницу а не перешел на другую
      if(window.location.pathname == window.sessionStorage.GETPath){
        var GETRequest = window.sessionStorage.GETRequest;
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
        window.location.assign(window.location.pathname+GETRequest);
      }else{
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
      }
   }
}());
//если передан определенный запрос с необходимым параметром
<?if($param['val']==(int)1):?>
    <script>
        // записываются параметры запроса и страница 
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('GETRequest', window.location.search);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('GETPath', window.location.pathname);
        // убирает запрос и адресной строки
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    </script>
<?else:?> // если запрос не валидный
    <script>
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    </script>
<?endif;?>
```

Правда есть ощущение что `window.location.assign(window.location.pathname+GETRequest);` можно сделать лаконичней без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно сохранить это в cookie
Получите ваши параметры с помощью location.search:

```
window.location.search
```

запишите их в куки

```
document.cookie = "name=Vasya";
```

а при загрузке страницы получение куки

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
      "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=
    ([^;]*)"
 )); return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;}
```

Так Вы сможете сохранить эти параметры запроса внутри браузера, но сами данные не сохранятся.
Как вариант, можно использовать вместо cookie использовать localStorage